# Smile wings and varswap pricing

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus, variance, volatility-smile, variance-swap

Is it true that far wings of the volatility smile have an outsized influence on the price of a variance swap? Is there a mathematical argument demonstrating this idea? What do we generally refer as far wings (5% probability to hit the level or 1% probability etc.)? I could find no paper detailing this dependence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main concern is usually for the far wing where strikes are low.

Variance swaps have a theoretical replication. The fair variance swap strike $K_{var}$  is computed as

$$ K^2_{var} = \frac{2*e^{rT}}{T} \left[ \int_0^{F(0)} \frac{P(K)}{\boldsymbol{K^2}} dK + \int_{F(0)}^\infty \frac{C(K)}{\boldsymbol{K^2}} dK \right] $$
where $T$ is the contracts maturity, $P(K)$ and $C(K)$ are European option prices with strike $K$ and maturity $T$ and $F(0)$ is the forward price. If strikes are very low, you end up with very small squared numbers, and huge weights.

There are two documents from JP Morgan [Variance Swaps](https://fdocuments.net/document/variance-swaps-jp-morgan.html) and [Just what you need to know about Variance Swaps](http://docs.sbossu.com/bossu-strasser-guichard-varswap.pdf) that contain the formula and details, with the latter being more concise. Personally, I recommend reading [Towards a Theory of Volatility Trading](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.27.6011&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Peter Carr et al.

In words: A vanilla option trader, following a delta-hedging strategy, is essentially replicating the payoff of a weighted variance swap where the daily squared returns are weighted by the option’s dollar gamma, which is highest near the strike. Taking this argument one step further, a fair variance swap can be shown to equal the integral of weighted prices of out-of-the-money options over all strikes. These weights are being inversely proportional to **squared strikes**, an application of the Black Scholes closed-form formula for gamma, which ensures results in constant dollar gamma as shown below.
[image]

One obvious problem here is that options markets are composed of a discrete set of option prices for a given maturity. Therefore, it is common to first compute a vol surface. Practically, it is desired to limit the integration region (strike range) to avoid issues with the weights (especially very small strikes are a concern because of the weighting with **squared strikes**). Where this truncation is done is probably market dependent and depends on the quality of the available vol surface.

On a side note, due to practical difficulties in replicating the actual log payout across strikes, the market for equity index Var swaps usually trades at a basis to the replicating portfolio.